# Can we start a process/flow on opportunity product record delete?

Tags: process-builder, flow

Is it possible to start a process/flow on opportunity product record delete?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Process builder can only fire when an object is either [created or updated](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_start.htm&type=0&language=en_US). For a flow you'll need a different trigger mechanism too.

You'll need an apex trigger. From there you could still activate a non grafphical visual flow if you prefer your business process logic to be in a flow rather than Apex.